# how to roll back a transaction happening between microservices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, microservices

we have `microservice` architecture where for most part each `microservice` is independent. But for some legacy reasons, there is a situation where we have to call another `microservice` from within another.

eg: the following method is part of `Legal Service`

```
@Autowired
public ServiceManager UserServiceManager;

public void updateUserLegalData(){

    //do db update of Legal info for the user

   userServiveManager.setAcceptedLegal(true);


}
```

There are two `db transactions` going on above. one is updating legalService db and other is updating UserService db. please NOTE userService is a `microservice`running on a separate VM.

we are seeing situations where legal Service db is updated but call to userService is failing (`Internal server error`). so this leaves the application in an inconsistent state. How can we fix this in a recommended way?

Thanks

Comment: If there are only two services, then one way is to call the 2nd service from the 1st service;s transactional method. First update the local db, then call the second service. If the second call fails, throw an Exception. That will result in a rollback on first as well. and if second succeeds you are happy to go with the db state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation can be handled only with JTA global/distributed transactions. JTA is part of Java EE standard and can have various implementors. Atomikos is often tool of choice.

[Here is good writeup from Dave Syer (Spring ecosystem contributor).](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) It contain also working examples. It's little bit outdated, but still relevant. You can apply some more modern Spring abstractions on top of his examples.

I created few [GitHub examples of JTA transactions](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/07-jta) for my book. Notice that there are errors simulated and transaction is spread across JMS and JDBC datasources.

**But also bear in mind that JTA transactions across various data sources are slow, because of 2-phased commit algorithm involved.** So often people try to avoid them and rather deal with inconsistencies somehow pragmatically.

Comment: http://www.apress.com/9781484207949. But it's not finished yet. Working on last chapter currently.

Comment: >`JTA transactions are slow and are nowadays often considered as architectural anti-pattern` - I think the reverse is true. JTA transactions are optimized to such degree these days that there's barely any overhead for using them. When you only use a single transactional resource or one tx resource and non-tx one LRCO can be applied as well, reducing any possible costs associated with 2-phase commits.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do distributed transactions.

For integration with your existing legacy system one approach could be a separate (micro)service which listens to update events from your userService and forwards the respective updates to the legalService.
Spring integration may be suitable for such a task.

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Well if you read little bit about the subject in the internet, it is a big debacle point at the moment but there is one answer that everybody agrees on it, distributed transactions are not way to go for it. They are too clumsy and buggy that we can't rely on them for data consistency.

So what is our options then, people are the moment trying to coordinate micro service transactions via Apache Kafka or with Event Source (which concentrate on saving events which are changing the data instead of saving the data itself). So what is the problem with those? Well they are quite different then usual programming model that we get used to and at technical and organisational point of view quite complex, so instead of programming for Business Problems, you start programming against the technical challenge.

So what is the alternative, I personally developed an another concept and wrote a blog about it, it might be interesting for you. In its basics, it uses full micro service design principles and Spring Boot + Netflix in a J2EE container and fully using the transactions, it is too long to write all details here, if you are interested you can read the from the link below.

[Micro Services and Transactions with Spring Boot + Netflix](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/micro-services-fan-out-transaction-problems-and-solutions-with-spring-bootjboss-and-netflix-eureka/)

Answer (score 1):

Transaction across microservices can become complex and can slow down the system, one of the best ways to solve the problem of distributed transactions is to avoid them completely.
If you avoid distributed transactions across microservices then you will not end up in such situation.

If at all you have to implement distributed transactions across microservices then I think there are a couple of ways :

**Two-phase commit protocol 
**Eventual Consistency**

In your case, I would recommend using message bus and flag to communicate among services , So if legal service adds the data into legal database put a lock on that record and send message on message bus , user service when it is up it will pick the message and update database at its end  and send ack message onto the message bus, once ack message is received remove the lock otherwise delete/rollback the record after certain time duration. This looks complex but reliable and failure-proof solution in your case.